# Regexp to match specific characters in tcl

Tags: regex, tcl, regsub

I have a variable that contains following characters

"@/$%&*#{}4g_.[]3435_.technology@lte042"

I want to match only "4g_.3435_.technologylte042" by excluding special characters

Code:

```
set a "@\/$%&*#[](){}4g_.[]3435_.technology@lte042"
regexp {[\w._-]+} $a match
puts $match
```

I got output :

```
4g_.3435_.technology
```

I am not getting remaining characters "lte042"

please help.

Comment: Note that `\w` already includes underscore -- http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm#M68

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you are trying to remove all non-word characters, rather than trying to find the first contiguous sequence of word characters. You could use a repeated search-and-replace:

```
regsub -all {[^\w._-]+} $a "" match
```

Another option is to use the `-all -inline` options to produce a list of matches instead of a single match. However, that will put spaces between the successive matches. Eg:

```
set a "@\/$%&*#[](){}4g_.[]3435_.technology@lte042"
set match [regexp -all -inline {[\w._-]+} $a]
puts $match
```

==>

```
4g_.3435_.technology lte042
```

The second `set` is necessary because the `-inline` option doesn't allow match variables to be specified as command parameters.

Comment: I tested your code. Still @ is remaining . output was "4g_.3435_.technology@lte042

Comment: @gpk: Sorry, missed the "repeated" option, `-all`. Fixed and tested.

Comment: Thanks...It worked...!! Is there a way to get same result using regexp.

Comment: @gpk: as far as I know, there is not. `regexp` returns one contiguous match, but you want the concatenation of all the matches. You could do that with an explicit loop, but it's easier to erase the parts that don't match, at least in this case.

Comment: @gpk: Added something fairly close, but it might not be exactly what you want.

Comment: One More thing to ask. In above example why there is no any space in case of [] character. Is that considered as word character.

Comment: @gpk: if I understand what you are asking, it is probably an artifact of TCL list flattening.

Comment: ok.Then how to get result including [] character by regsub or regexp.    eg:        []4g_.[]3435_.technology lte042

Comment: @gpk: In TCL, "a[]b" is the string "ab"; `[]` is an (empty) command substitution so it is substituted by the result of the empty command which is the empty string. If you want a string to include `[`, you need to use `{a[]b}` instead of quotes, in order to prevent the command substitution (which is why you normally have to write regular expressions inside braces instead of quotes). ... An SO comment thread is not an appropriate place for a TCL tutorial, though. If you have specific questions about TCL, ask them as separate questions.

Comment: Use `join` to combine list elements into one string. The optional argument after the list to join is the string to use as the joiner; try the empty string there.

Answer (score 0):

One step closer:

```
% set s {@/$%&*#{}4g_.[]3435_.technology@lte042}
@/$%&*#{}4g_.[]3435_.technology@lte042
% join [regexp -inline -all {[][\w._-]+} $s] {}
4g_.[]3435_.technologylte042
```

Documentation:
[join](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/join.htm),
[regexp](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regexp.htm),
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm),
[Syntax of Tcl regular expressions](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm)